# Assigning a link and description to a column cards dynamically

Tags: javascript

I want to create column cards (like buttons).
in that cards, description should appear in its top and when it is clicked, separate link should be opened in new page.

every cards has its own description and link.it should not be hard coded by directly assigning the desc and link to it.and every function and elements should be assigned in javascript file not html.

the desc and link should given in an array like

```
Table={{"desc":"apple","link":"www.google.com"},{"desc":"banana","link":"www.youtube.com"}}
```

I tried this code and I'm getting only one card with last description and link

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
      var temp=my.Table[i].link;
      $('.demo').html('<div class="column"><p id="i"></p></div>');
      document.getElementById(i).innerHTML ='<a href="' + temp + '">' + my.Table[i].desc + '</a>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate the table object, after `append` what you should use.
HTML code:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"> -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="demo">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the jquery code looks like the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  const table=[{"desc":"apple","link":"www.google.com"},{"desc":"banana","link":"www.youtube.com"}];
  table.forEach((v, i)=>{
    $('.demo').append('<div class="column"><p id="temp_'+i+'"><a href="' + v.link + '">' + v.desc + '</a></p></div>');
  });
});
```